why is there a difference between different useField in Formik
I'm using formik for writing forms, and in the form there is a field which takes emails, each email is selected through a dropdown (here FormSelect), I'm setting the value of an email using useField.
the emailField value when i console log it is
enter image description here
i see a uuid for its value,
but when i console log the testFieldName i can see it as undefined
enter image description here
I want to understand why is there a difference between both, both are strings for useField and emailFieldName and testFieldName both are string
interface IEventMailComponentField {
    mfItem: string;
    emailList: Array<SelectOption>
}
```

```
export function EmailComponent({ emailList, mfItem}: IEventMailComponentField){
    console.log( "test", mfItem)
    const emailFieldName = `${mfItem}`
    const [ emailField, , emailFieldHelpers ] = useField(emailFieldName)
    // const testFieldName = `${fieldName}.emails`
    // const [ testField, , testFieldHelpers ] = useField(testFieldName)
    console.log(emailField)
    const value = useMemo(() => emailList.find(item => item.value === emailField.value), [emailField.value, emailList])
     return (
        <FormSelect
          key={emailFieldName}
          name={emailFieldName}
          label="Send Certificate To"
          controlled
          required
          options={emailList}
          value={value}
          onChange={ (option : SelectOption ) => {
            const v = option.value;
            delete emailField.value
            emailFieldHelpers.setValue(v)
          }}
        />
  )
}
```


```
<MultiField >
     {({ mfItem })=> (
         <EmailComponent emailList={emailOptionsDeDuped}  mfItem = {mfItem}/>
     )}
</MultiField>
```


Can i know what is the difference between both of these

